# Change package for plot in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am a user of R Studio.  few days ago I created a certain plot:

[Plot type 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT0jM.png)

I assume that it is obtained by the package time series. The code looks as follows

```
plot(x = DCC_plot$BMW[,1],ylim=c(0,1), xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL,main="BMW",         major.format ="%Y",major.ticks= "years",minor.ticks = FALSE,type='n',yaxt='n')
lines(x = DCC_plot$BMW[,1],  col = "darkblue",lty=1,lwd=2)
lines(x = DCC_plot$BMW[,2], col = "darkred",lty=1, lwd=2)
axis(2,yaxp = c(0, 1, 4))
```

When I recreated the plot today, I obbtained the following version. Looks like an xts, and teh same code as above has been used. What shoud I do to obtain the same plot as before?

[Plot type 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COryS.png)

Answer (score 0):

By chance, had you loaded a package in the R Studio *console* and not within your script code? In that way, you may have lost the R environment and the certain package that gave the display seen in plot 1.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. I hope that someone knows how to obtain the style of graph 1.

Comment: You should be able to check .Rhistory, or the history pane in R studio, and search for library() or require() callls

Comment: I have retried every possible combination of prevously used packages. Does their order has an influence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the most recently loaded package will "mask" or usurp other packages when they share a common function like plot().